# Fill matrix using names with Rcpp

Tags: r, performance, matrix, rcpp

Suppose that named elements of a vector - stored in list - should be assigned to the matching columns of a matrix (see example below).

```
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(123)
myList <- list()
for(i in 1:10000) {
 myList[[i]] <- list(sample(setNames(rnorm(5), sample(LETTERS[1:5])), ceiling(runif(1,1,4))))
}

myMatrix <- matrix(NA, ncol = 5, nrow = 10000)
colnames(myMatrix) <- LETTERS[1:5]
for(i in 1:10000) {
 myMatrix[i, match(names(myList[[i]][[1]]), colnames(myMatrix))] <- myList[[i]][[1]] 
}
myList[[6]][[1]]
myMatrix[6,]

microbenchmark(for(i in 1:10000) {myMatrix[i, match(names(myList[[i]][[1]]), colnames(myMatrix))] <- myList[[i]][[1]]}, times = 10)
```

In this example, elements of 10,000 vectors are assigned to the matching columns of a matrix.

**Problem**

The assignment is slow (approximately 3.5 seconds)!

**Question**

How can I speed up this process in R or with Rcpp?

Comment: Instead of operating on each element, you could `unlist` "myList" and `match` the names of the resulting vector to `colnames(myMatrix)`. The respective row indices seem to be `rep(1:length(myList), lapply(myList, function(elt) length(elt[[1]])))`. Then, you could use matrix indexing as described in `?Extract` / "Matrices and arrays"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rbindlist` from package data.table. It can bind by matching column names.

```
library(microbenchmark)
n <- 10000
set.seed(123)
myList <- list()
for(i in 1:n) {
  myList[[i]] <- list(sample(setNames(rnorm(5), sample(LETTERS[1:5])), ceiling(runif(1,1,4))))
}

myMatrix <- matrix(NA, ncol = 5, nrow = n)
colnames(myMatrix) <- LETTERS[1:5]

library(data.table)
microbenchmark(match = for(i in 1:n) {myMatrix[i, match(names(myList[[i]][[1]]), colnames(myMatrix))] <- myList[[i]][[1]]}, 
               rbindlist = {
                 myMatrix1 <- as.matrix(rbindlist(lapply(myList, 
                                                         function(x) as.list(unlist(x))), 
                                                  fill = TRUE))
                 myMatrix1 <- myMatrix1[, order(colnames(myMatrix1))]
                 },
               times = 10)
#Unit: milliseconds
#     expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval cld
#    match 1392.52949 1496.40382 1599.63584 1605.39080 1690.98410 1761.67322    10   b
#rbindlist   48.76146   50.29176   51.66355   51.10672   53.75465   54.93798    10  a

all.equal(myMatrix, myMatrix1)
#TRUE
```